# FTP upload triggering email send, how are the emails then sent? 1 Bulk send or 1 by 1 as each line of the file is processed?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation

We are wondering if we use a "file drop trigger" to trigger an automation in the SFMC, when that file is uploaded to the ftp will the resulting email sends go out in one large bulk send in a matter of secs/minutes or would each email be sent out one at a time as the file is processed line by line?

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired outcome on this?

If it's how fast the emails go out then I'm not sure if there's a issue. With a file drop triggered automation you can have this go out within a minute or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Automation Studio can only send [User Initiated (UI) Send Definition](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/send_email_activity/) emails, it would send the emails out in bulk - with a single JobID.

You would need to have the file drop trigger the automation, [import the data](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_an_import_activity/) from the file and then set up your UI email to send out to that audience (same as any normal email send you would do.).

The only way to get it to send individually is to set up a [script activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/create_a_script_activity/) that would initiate a trigger send definition via [AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createTriggeredSend.htm) or [SSJS](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/server_side_javascript_sample_code/perform_a_triggered_send_defintion/).